# generated express project does not call routes/index.js but load public/index.html

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express and using express-generator to get working skeleton of project.

I use following command

1. npm install express-generator
2. express --no-view backend
3. cd backend
4. npm install
5. SET DEBUG=backend:* & npm start

Now 1 route is working fine and other is not

```
           1 - http://localhost:3000/            //always load public/index.html and not executing routes/index.js

           2 - http://localhost:3000/users       //work fine and executing routes/users.js

    Its only generated code making changes index.js is not getting effect.
```

Thanks in Advance

regards

Answer (score 0):

You have defined two routes for your home page. `index.html` is overriding `index.js` you can use one of them not both.

Comment: I want to use 1 index.js. but the framework load index.html. How to force express to load index.js

Comment: remove `index.html`